# jQuery Fileupload Blueimp Ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a set of jQuery tabs that each contain a different set of data. When a tab is clicked an ajax function runs to get some data out of the database to populate the tab content area.

This all works fine, except that one of my tabs contains a jQuery fileupload form. On initial tab load the form works. When directing away from the upload tab, and then back to it the form no longer works.

I assume this is because the form needs to be re-initialized on page load.

I've tried setting up an interval that runs and if the form is visible, initialize.

```
var find_uploader = setInterval(function() {

  if ( jQuery( '#upload_content' ).is( ':visible' ) ) { 

    jQuery('#upload-form').fileupload();

  }

},2400);
```

but no dice. I can't seem to figure out how to re-initialize the blueimp file upload plugin. Essentially when loading the page content via ajax, the plugin is unable to be initialized more than once.

Comment: your code is not sufficient to understand

Comment: You need to set time in your interval i think --- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: @Prashant , if you know the plugin the code is sufficient to understand. Time has been set in the timer.